# C# Windows Service creates trace file but never writes to it

Tags: c#, windows-services, file-permissions

I have a windows service created using the "new ... c# service" menu in VS 2010. In the constructor I have:

```
TextWriterTraceListener tr1 = new TextWriterTraceListener( System.IO.File.CreateText("d:\\output\\test.log"));
Trace.Listeners.Add(tr1);
Trace.WriteLine("Created");
```

Setting the service to run in either LocalService or LocalSystem accounts (WinXP) I get the file created when the service starts, but it's always empty. Adding a Flush() call to the destructor doesn't help. I have more trace calls in the OnStart/OnStop/OnPause/OnContinue methods.

*(edit)* I have trace and debug enabled in the project - the trace output file *is* being created, it's just empty.

The service will pull records out of a database and write files to disk for a messaging system we have to interface with. So the log file problem is the just first instance of a broader problem - I need to be able to write to a user-selected messaging directory.

This looks like the symptoms in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858597/why-wont-my-windows-service-write-to-my-log-file) but also I get the problem as LocalSystem (which I thought had too many permissions so was deprecated).

1. What am I doing wrong with the trace calls? (why is the file created but nothing written to it?)
2. If I want my service to run in the LocalService account is there some way to get the installer to give it permission to write to a folder/subtree?
3. Or should I be running the service as LocalSystem?
4. is this re-implementation of [Debug.Launch/EnsureWriter][2] a sane solution? I'm more inclined to say "why is the writer null" than paste code from elsewhere like that.

thanks for any help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you sure you have the `TRACE` symbol defined for your project?  All the [`System.Diagnostics.Trace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace.aspx) code is conditionally compiled in based on this symbol.  Note that you will still need to flush the trace output to ensure all the lines are written (or else set `Trace.AutoFlush` to true).

As a side note, I would recommend against the use of the static `Trace` methods and suggest at least using [`System.Diagnostics.TraceSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracesource.aspx).

Comment: Setting trace.AutoFlush to true fixed the problem if I run as LocalSystem rather than LocalService. Having "~MyClass(){Trace.Flush();}" didn't help. But yes, trace was enabled for the project.

Answer (score 1):

try configuring tracing in the app.exe.config of the application.

```
<configuration>
   <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
        <source name="System.ServiceModel" 
            switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
            propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
         <add name="traceListener" 
           type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" 
           initializeData= "c:\log\Traces.svclog" />
        </listeners>
     </source>
    </sources>
   </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

You can do this by using the service config editor under Microsoft Windows SDK tools.

Comment: No, it works for web and windows applications. for web you need to add it to the web.config and for exes it will be in app.exe.config.refer msdn documentation here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.xmlwritertracelistener.aspx windows service is still an exe and it should work. Or you can write a custom tracelistener and configure the same in the config file.