# Windows service rights to write in log file

Tags: c#, windows-services, nlog

I have created a Windows service using C# that writes logs (with [NLog](http://nlog-project.org)) in `C:\ProgramData`.
When I debug the service (on my Windows 7) (using the code written above), the log file is correctly created and log records correctly written.
But when I install the service on my server which runs on Windows server 2008 (*x86*), no log file is created (I have also checked in `C:\Windows\System32\`, nothing there).

I suspect that it is an authorization problem so how can I know what rights is my service using?

*PS:* I have installed my service using the command line `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil.exe C:\PathToMyService\MyService.exe` with Administrator rights.

Comment: The rights will be whatever identity your service is running under, not the identity that was used to install it. See here for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/858597/why-wont-my-windows-service-write-to-my-log-file

Comment: C:\windows\system32 should not be used to write log files to. This is an important operating system directory. Also C:\ProgramData us were application binaries reside and should not be used for log files. You should write log files for application services to C:\AppData\local\... or to the Windows Event Log on a Windows 2008 server. You will also have less issue with permissions if you do it this way, in addition to it been good practice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run `services.msc`, find your service right click and select `Properties`. Check the `Log On` tab to see which account your service is running under.

As for your problem, by default I think most services run under the `Local System Account` which I would assume has permissions to write to the `C:\ProgramData` directory. Have you made sure the `nlog.config` file is deployed with your service?

Comment: Arg, just figured that the nlog.config file was not deployed with my service. Fixed!

Comment: @Leito - your question sounded all too familiar... happened to me a good few times!

Comment: What did do to ensure that the NLog.config file is deployed with the service? Isn't "Always Copy to Output Folder" enough?

Answer (score 1):

You should see your service in the windows control panel fpr services. In the contextmenu you can see the user which runs your service. You can even change the user running your service there.

You have to give that user the right to write in your log directory.