# Log file not generated within the WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF service that is supposed to generate several log files. If I [self-host as managed application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/how-to-host-a-wcf-service-in-a-managed-application), the log files are generated. But if I host the very same [Wcf service in a Windows Managed Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-host-a-wcf-service-in-a-managed-windows-service), then no log files are generated. It is extremely important to have those log files while hosting the WCF service in Windows Managed service.

------------------------------ UPDATE --------------------------------------
The following code snippet hopefully provide some hint on what is missing in the process:

```
public class WinManagedServiceHost: ServiceBase
{
    // create an instance of EventLog
    private readonly EventLog _eventLog1 = null;
    private int _eventId = 1;
    private ServiceHost _diagnosticServiceHost = null;

    public WinManagedServiceHost(string[] args)
    {
        ServiceName = "WinManagedWcfServiceHost";
        CanStop = true;
        CanShutdown = true;
        AutoLog = false;

        var eventSourceName = "WinManagedWcfServiceHostEventSource";
        var logName = "WinManagedWcfServiceHostNewLog";

        if (args.Length > 0)
        {
            eventSourceName = args[0];
        }

        if (args.Length > 1)
        {
            logName = args[1];
        }

        //define the custom event log
        _eventLog1 = new EventLog();

        if (!EventLog.SourceExists(eventSourceName))
        {
            /*
             * create a custom log by calling the CreateEventSource method and specifying the source
             * string and the name of the log file we want to create
             */
            EventLog.CreateEventSource(eventSourceName, logName);
        }

        _eventLog1.Source = eventSourceName;
        _eventLog1.Log = logName;
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Run(new WinManagedServiceHost(args));
    }

    public void OnTimer(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs args)
    {
        // TODO: Insert monitoring activities here.
        _eventLog1.WriteEntry("Monitoring the System", EventLogEntryType.Information, _eventId++);
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            // Update the service state to Start Pending.
            var serviceStatus = new ServiceStatus { dwCurrentState = ServiceState.SERVICE_START_PENDING, dwWaitHint = 100000 };
            SetServiceStatus(ServiceHandle, ref serviceStatus);

            _eventLog1.WriteEntry("In OnStart.");
            // Set up a timer that triggers every minute.
            var timer = new Timer();
            timer.Interval = 60000; // 60 seconds
            timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimer);
            timer.Start();

            _diagnosticServiceHost?.Close();

            // parse service host configuration info
            var Desktop = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("Desktop").Trim();
            var address = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("localhost").Trim();
            var port = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("port").Trim();
            var protocol = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("protocol").Trim();

            _eventLog1.WriteEntry($"Querying {protocol}://{Desktop}:{port}/ ...");

            var ipQuery = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
                .SelectMany(
                    ni => ni.GetIPProperties()
                        .UnicastAddresses.Select(ip => ip.Address.MapToIPv4())
                        .Where(ipc => ipc.Equals(IPAddress.Parse(Desktop))))
                .FirstOrDefault();

            if (ipQuery != null)
            {
                address = ipQuery.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                _eventLog1.WriteEntry($"Network interface for {Desktop} could NOT be found, running locally.....");
            }

            // create a URI to serve as the base tcp address
            var baseAddress = new Uri($"{protocol}://{address}:{port}/");

            _diagnosticServiceHost = new ServiceHost(new WcfServiceImpl(), baseAddress);

            var tcpBinding = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None)
                             {
                                 SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 45, 0),
                                 CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(3, 45, 0),
                                 ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(5, 0, 0)
                             };

            _diagnosticServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IDiagnosticService), tcpBinding, "V5DiagnosticsService");

            _diagnosticServiceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(new ServiceMetadataBehavior());

            _diagnosticServiceHost.Open();

            _eventLog1.WriteEntry(
                $"The service is ready {_diagnosticServiceHost.Description.Endpoints?.FirstOrDefault()?.Address.Uri.ToString()}");

            // Update the service state to Running.
            serviceStatus.dwCurrentState = ServiceState.SERVICE_RUNNING;
            SetServiceStatus(ServiceHandle, ref serviceStatus);

            //write the service status to an XML file
        }
        catch (CommunicationException ce)
        {
            _eventLog1.WriteEntry($"An exception occurred: {ce.Message}");
            _diagnosticServiceHost?.Abort();
        }
    }
}

public class ProjectInstaller : Installer
{
    private ServiceProcessInstaller _process;
    private ServiceInstaller _service;

    public ProjectInstaller()
    {
        _process = new ServiceProcessInstaller
        {
            Account = ServiceAccount.LocalSystem                
        };

        _service = new ServiceInstaller
        {
            ServiceName = "WinManagedWcfServiceHost",
            DisplayName = "WinManagedWcfServiceHost",
            Description = "A WCF Service that takes System Diagnostics Request",
            StartType = ServiceStartMode.Manual
        };
        

        Installers.Add(_process);
        Installers.Add(_service);
    }

    protected override void OnBeforeInstall(IDictionary savedState)
    {
        var parameter = "WinManagedWcfServiceHostEventSource1\" \"WinManagedWcfServiceHostNewLog1";
        Context.Parameters["assemblypath"] = "\"" + Context.Parameters["assemblypath"] + "\" \"" + parameter + "\"";
        base.OnBeforeInstall(savedState);
    }
}
```

After successful build, it has been installed by installutil.exe from the developer command prompt with as admin.

How to set the permissions correctly in the code ?
------------------------------ UPDATE --------------------------------------

Comment: You need to provide _way_ more information about how logging is implemented, a self contained example (maybe) that fails to work, etc. Without that, it could be many things, including, but not limited to: an unobserved exception/error, permissions (different service user than when running otherwise), relative directories (so the file is in a other location than you expect), etc. In general, there is nothing preventing you to write a log file from a Windows Service.

Comment: [mre], a simple Webservice with only one method and logging. But from my reading of your question i will look into the account that execute the service. Perhaps he has no write to write on the disk

Comment: You likely don't have permissions set correctly

Comment: You can refer to this link to see which permissions your service is running under:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7525854/windows-service-rights-to-write-in-log-file