# C# Service Programming Issue with starting

Tags: c#, service

I have written a service and done so using C# with the appropriate service methods etc in the code to start a service, its built and installed as a service, the service starts fine, however I don't see a process running and I also don't see it writing the log it should be writing as an output file. I do notice it picks up if I brute force and click the exe myself however obviously that's not intended behaviour. Any ideas why this may be occurring? I installed it using installutil and started it several ways (services.msc, net start) none of them work really.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: C# services don't run in the same user context. For example, you can't take a screenshot of the user's desktop, because the desktop session your service is running in (session 0 i think?) *has* no desktop to take a screenshot of. Be careful about how you write to the log file. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/858597/why-wont-my-windows-service-write-to-my-log-file

As for the process, might it be running as SYSTEM? Are you looking at "Show processes from all users" in Task Manager?

Comment: Can you show the code you've used for the start process ? Ie the bit in program.cs and in your service's onstart process ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked in the Windows Event Log to see if you get messages to say the service has started? Are there any errors in there? If it says it's started, and there aren't any errors, your service was probably started okay, but is failing to do what you want.

Instead of writing to a log file, consider writing to the Event Log - this is the preferred behaviour for services. Log4Net can help with this, but it's not too hard to write yourself.

It's also useful to write your service so that it can also be started from the command line, for debugging purposes. Again, you don't have to do all the work, TopShelf can help with this.